# Drupal 8 render a block in controller?

Tags: php, drupal-8

I have written this code to render the block in a controller but it didn't work for me (maybe some namespace issues)

```
$block = \Drupal\block_content\Entity\BlockContent::load('right_navigation_block');
$menu = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getViewBuilder('block')->view($block);
```

Answer (score 0):

First, inspect the contents of `$block` and `$menu` to be sure you are not making typos and everything is loading fine. Use `ksm` from the `devel` and `kint` modules to print nice what is into those variables.

If something looks weird, then you can go to the link below to look at how to programmatically display a block:

https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/171686/how-can-i-programmatically-display-a-block

Good luck!